# Got Python bigquery.jobs.create permission error

Tags: python, google-bigquery

O want to write a python script that upload data from a file to a bigquery table.

here is the code:

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client(project=project_id, location='US').from_service_account_json('my-key.json')

dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_name)
client.load_table_from_file(filename, table_ref)
```

I am using a gcp vm created in the same project as where my bigquery table is. I am also using a service account that has Bigquery admin role.

I have an error that says that the user doesn't have the `bigquery.jobs.create` permission.

I don't know if it is a useful information but i am able to read my table.

I don't know what to do.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi - it sounds like your service account does not have the correct level of permissions. BigQuery Admin does have `bigquery.jobs.create` permission, so check your service account does indeed have this. Check out the roles page on GCP to check which  titles have which roles: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles

Comment: It seems a bad SA role missing, as @BenP already pointed out. It would be helpful to isolate your issue if you could share the error message (censoring any kind of personal information) and double check the `bigquery.jobs.create` permission.